# Как сделать, чтобы popup не открывался вместе со страницей?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

мне надо сделать чтобы popup открывался только по нажатию кнопки, а он открывается вместе со страницей, как это можно исправить?

```js
// Pop-up
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Скрыть PopUp при загрузке страницы    
  PopUpHide();
  $("#popup1").hide();
});
//Функция отображения PopUp
function PopUpShow() {
  $("#popup1").show();
}
//Функция скрытия PopUp
function PopUpHide() {
  $("#popup1").hide();
}
```

```css
.product {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.product-text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.product-itemss {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: (1fr)[2];
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[2];
  grid-template: repeat(2, 1fr)/repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 15px;
}

.product-item {
  height: 390px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.product-description {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.product-price {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.product-img {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.product-texti {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 38px;
}

.product-btn {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-image: url("/img/btn.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.product-btn :hover {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 25px black;
}

.b-popup {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

.b-popup-content {
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
  width: 1110px;
  height: 773px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.7);
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.b-popup-content-textm {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.b-popup-content-close {
  float: right;
}

.b-popup-content-close :hover {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.b-popup-form {
  float: left;
}

.b-popup input {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 60px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Grtsk Tera', sans-serif;
}

.b-popup input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 0;
  width: 220px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <a name="product"></a>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2 class="product-text">Цены</h2>
    <div class="product-itemss">
      <div class="product-items">
        <div class="product-item">
          <h3 class="product-texti">Landing page</h3>
          <img src="/img/Porsche.png" alt="" class="product-img">
          <p class="product-description">· От 4 до 12 блоков<br>· Слайдер, анимации <br>· Адаптивный дизайн</p>
          <p class="product-price">Цена от 8000₽</p>
          <a class="product-btn" href="javascript:PopUpShow()"><span>Заказать</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-items">
        <div class="product-item">
          <h3 class="product-texti">Оформление соц.сетей</h3>
          <img src="/img/Oformlenie.png" alt="" class="product-img">
          <p class="product-description">Вконтакте, Instagram, YouTube, Twitch</p>
          <p class="product-price">Цена от 500₽</p>
          <a class="product-btn" href="javascript:PopUpShow()"><span>Заказать</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-items">
        <div class="product-item">
          <h3 class="product-texti">Превью для<br>YouTube канала</h3>
          <img src="/img/Prewiev.png" alt="" class="product-img">
          <p class="product-description">Привлекающая картинка для вашего видео</p>
          <p class="product-price">Цена от 400₽</p>
          <a class="product-btn" href="javascript:PopUpShow()"><span>Заказать</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-items">
        <div class="product-item">
          <h3 class="product-texti">Фирменный<br>логотип</h3>
          <img src="/img/Logotype.png" alt="" class="product-img">
          <p class="product-description">Современный и красивый логотип</p>
          <p class="product-price">Цена от 500₽</p>
          <a class="product-btn" href="javascript:PopUpShow()"><span>Заказать</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pop-up">
  <div class="b-popup" id="popup1">
    <div class="b-popup-content">
      <h2 class="b-popup-content-textm">Мы всегда на связи<br>Пишите нам!</h2>
      <a class="b-popup-content-close" href="javascript:PopUpHide()"><img src="/img/Close.svg" alt=""></a>
      <form action="#" class="b-popup-form">
        <input type="text" name="example" list="exampleList" placeholder="Меня интересует...">
        <datalist id="exampleList">
                <option value="Сайта под ключ">
                <option value="Дизайн сайта">
                <option value="Дизайн приложения">
                <option value="HTML/CSS верстка">  
                <option value="Дизайн для соц.сетей">
                <option value="Превью"></option>
                <option value="Логотип"></option>
            </datalist>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ваш email">
        <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Расскажите о своём проекте">
        <input type="text" name="money" placeholder="Планируемый бюджет">
        <input type="file" name="f">
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить файл">
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Прошу прощения, если мой вопрос покажется глупым, пожалуйста не снижайте мне рейтинг.*

Comment: А тут вообще никак не отображается popup :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрывайте блок изначально при помощи стилей например `.pop-up { display: none; }`

Функцию отображения/скрытия блока используйте `onclick` например: `<a class="product-btn" href="#" onclick="PopUpShow()"><span>Заказать</span></a>`

Тогда функция отображения PopUp будет:

```
function PopUpShow() {
  $(".pop-up").show();
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за правильный ответ, Вы мне очень сильно помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так. Немного переделал под универсальный вариант.
Добавляете в элемент `data-action="openModal"` (либо `data-action="closeModal"`) и `data-id="айди_модального_окна"` и по щелчку на него(Например, на текст) будет открываться (закрываться) нужная модалка

```js
//Функция отображения PopUp
$('[data-action="openModal"').click(function(){
  modalID = '#'+$(this).data('id');
  $(modalID).show();
})

//Функция скрытия PopUp
$('[data-action="closeModal"').click(function(){
  modalID = '#'+$(this).data('id');
  $(modalID).hide();
})
```

```css
.product {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.product-text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.product-itemss {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: (1fr)[2];
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[2];
  grid-template: repeat(2, 1fr)/repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 15px;
}

.product-item {
  height: 390px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.product-description {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.product-price {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.product-img {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.product-texti {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 38px;
}

.product-btn {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-image: url("/img/btn.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.product-btn :hover {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 25px black;
}

.b-popup {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  display: none;
}

.b-popup-content {
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
  width: 1110px;
  height: 773px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.7);
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.b-popup-content-textm {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.b-popup-content-close {
  float: right;
}

.b-popup-content-close :hover {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.b-popup-form {
  float: left;
}

.b-popup input {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 60px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-family: 'Grtsk Tera', sans-serif;
}

.b-popup input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 0;
  width: 220px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <a name="product"></a>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2 class="product-text">Цены</h2>
    <div class="product-itemss">
      <div class="product-items">
        <div class="product-item">
          <h3 class="product-texti">Landing page</h3>
          <img src="/img/Porsche.png" alt="" class="product-img">
          <p class="product-description">· От 4 до 12 блоков<br>· Слайдер, анимации <br>· Адаптивный дизайн</p>
          <p class="product-price">Цена от 8000₽</p>
          <a class="product-btn" data-action="openModal" data-id="popup1"><span>Заказать</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-items">
        <div class="product-item">
          <h3 class="product-texti">Оформление соц.сетей</h3>
          <img src="/img/Oformlenie.png" alt="" class="product-img">
          <p class="product-description">Вконтакте, Instagram, YouTube, Twitch</p>
          <p class="product-price">Цена от 500₽</p>
          <a class="product-btn" data-action="openModal" data-id="popup1"><span>Заказать</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-items">
        <div class="product-item">
          <h3 class="product-texti">Превью для<br>YouTube канала</h3>
          <img src="/img/Prewiev.png" alt="" class="product-img">
          <p class="product-description">Привлекающая картинка для вашего видео</p>
          <p class="product-price">Цена от 400₽</p>
          <a class="product-btn" data-action="openModal" data-id="popup1"><span>Заказать</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-items">
        <div class="product-item">
          <h3 class="product-texti">Фирменный<br>логотип</h3>
          <img src="/img/Logotype.png" alt="" class="product-img">
          <p class="product-description">Современный и красивый логотип</p>
          <p class="product-price">Цена от 500₽</p>
          <a class="product-btn" data-action="openModal" data-id="popup1"><span>Заказать</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pop-up">
  <div class="b-popup" id="popup1">
    <div class="b-popup-content">
      <h2 class="b-popup-content-textm">Мы всегда на связи<br>Пишите нам!</h2>
      <a class="b-popup-content-close" data-action="closeModal" data-id="popup1"><img src="/img/Close.svg" alt=""></a>
      <form action="#" class="b-popup-form">
        <input type="text" name="example" list="exampleList" placeholder="Меня интересует...">
        <datalist id="exampleList">
                <option value="Сайта под ключ">
                <option value="Дизайн сайта">
                <option value="Дизайн приложения">
                <option value="HTML/CSS верстка">  
                <option value="Дизайн для соц.сетей">
                <option value="Превью"></option>
                <option value="Логотип"></option>
            </datalist>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ваш email">
        <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Расскажите о своём проекте">
        <input type="text" name="money" placeholder="Планируемый бюджет">
        <input type="file" name="f">
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить файл">
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, что попытались мне помочь, но к сожалению этот вариант мне не подошёл :(